# complex java regex to match variety of fields

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write java regex to match variety of fields  like -

> username 
>   userid 
>   user_id 
>   user_login 
>   vb_login_username 
>   login_id 
>   user_name 
>   user 
>   uname 
>   txtusername 
>   j_username 
>   adminName 
>   loginuser 
>  
>   webvars.username 
>   josso%5Fusername 
>   lems.username 
>   tl_login 
>   _58_login 
>   user-id 
>   pppoe_authentication_username 
>   user 
>   os_username 
>   login 
>   login_id 
>   login_info 
>   proxy_login 
>   remote_login 
>   authorization_username 
>   auth_username 
>   default_username 
>   username_raw

I tried something like -

```
String pattern1 = "(.*)((?:user|login|u)(?:(?<=_)(?=(?:name|id))))(.*)";
```

But its not working for all the fields.

I think I need to write conditional regex e.g. if there is "_" or "-" after "user" or "login" string then there should be "info" or "name" followed "_".

If underscore is not there then there should not be anything after "user" or "login".

Thanks, 
Sachin

Comment: Let's make our lives simple.  How about using `input.contains("user") || input.contains("name") || input.contains("login")` ?

Comment: `clasg_the_amuser` ;) Should that match?

Comment: There other fields like user_email or login_server I want to ignore.

Comment: Wow! That really complicates things. Was gonna suggest something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/pN4yM3/1), but that last condition... I dunno.

Comment: regex is not at all a good solution. I see you know what you want , best is prepare a file something like .properties and build a hashmap with key as the input and value as boolean : `isAllowed` or not. That way you don't need to modify your code once your write, just modify your properties file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern:

```
String pattern = "username|userid|user_id|user_login|vb_login_username|login_id|user_name|user|uname|txtusername|j_username|adminName|loginuser|webvars.username|josso%5Fusername|lems.username|tl_login|_58_login|user-id|pppoe_authentication_username|user|os_username|login|login_id|login_info|proxy_login|remote_login|authorization_username|auth_username|default_username|username_raw";
```

Can you see that it's not the best approach to use `regex`? All other patterns will either be a variation of this pattern or will accept more tokens then you want.

`regex` defines a regular language. If a regular language has finite number of words, the regex containing all of them with alternative is ok. You can try to find a `minimal dfa` and then convert it to a regex, but believe me: it's not a way you want to follow.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Will this regex be faster or putting these strings in set and lookup inputs in this set?

Comment: In theory it should be parallel implementation so it would be faster.

Comment: I have threads in my app... but one of these will have advantages over other?

Comment: I meant that Java developers should have implemented it parallel, however I don't know how their matching works. If you want to use regex, the one I gave is the best one. Using a hashSet is a good idea. Then you just add words that you accept to a hash set and receive O(1) check possibility.

Answer (score -1):

This is a real complex task, but this might take you a bit on the way:

```
(?!.*(email|server))(^|\b|_)(login|user)(?:[_-]?(?:name|id|login|user))?
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pN4yM3/2).

(Just) added a negative look-ahead in the beginning, to disallow certain words. Then a test for the word `login` or `user`, followed by an optional `_` or `-`, followed by any of the word `name`, `id`, `login` or `user`.

It does't completely do the job, but combined with the previous answer (deleted) and xenteros'es, It might do it.

It matches all of the fields in your example, except `uname` , `txtusername` and `josso%5Fusername`. So you could either put those as a separate option, or complicate the regex further *(no, don't!)*.

Comment: It's always gratifying when people find that me spending time to come up with a solution for a person in need of assistance, decides to down-vote **without leaving a comment** :@.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and efforts.  After going through the comments/answers I think its better to have a set of strings and for every input string we can check whether that input is present in the set.<br>
Which is more performant regex or lookup into set because my application receives inputs at very high rate.